# Trying to open PBI Desktop from anaconda prompt

Tags: python, powershell, command-line, powerbi, anaconda

I'm trying to open PBI from the anaconda prompt but it just returns the path, I recently received a new laptop after my old laptop's hard drive failed. On my old laptop this worked fine and I was able to run python scripts to import the data. Now I can't open PBI from the anaconda prompt and without it, PBI gives an error saying numpy isn't installed. Can someone help solve this issue? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Use the `&` operator to invoke a command stored in a string: `& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\PBIDesktop.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

To start any executable via PowerShell, it's pretty common to use 'Start-Process.' [Microsoft Help Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2)

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\PBIDesktop.exe"
```

While a less efficient than your previous way of operating, this should suffice as a PowerShell way of accomplishing the task at hand.

Otherwise, Mathias' comment about including the ampersand would be another way to accomplish this.